# Election fraud on Apple.SE!!1!

Tags: support

OK, now I have your attention.

There seems to be a glitch on [Apple.SE about](https://apple.stackexchange.com/about) page, where our latest [Valued Associate](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/welcome-valued-associate-josh-heyer/) **Shog9** appears on the elected moderator list, even though he wasn't elected.

See:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Curses! My ballot-stuffing has been detected! And I would have gotten away with it too, if not for you meddling kids...

(I changed OpenIDs and didn't update everywhere. Sorry for the confusion - the about page should appear correctly now.)

Comment: +1 for Scooby Doo reference.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a glitch with new employees; after Shog logs out and back in, apparently, his name will vanish from that list.

Comment: OK, well, I pinged him on The Tavern so that will probably resolved itself any time soon :)